# How to find size of static allocations from binary?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Is it possible to determine the total amount of memory dedicated to static and global variables from the binary?  I'm looking for a Linux utility that reads an elf file and figures out how much memory is pre-allocated for variables.

Answer (score 12):

The `size` utility will report that, under "data".

```
> size ./my_program
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use...

```
objdump -h progfile
```

which will list the "headers". Find the `.data` header and check the size column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nm` command (or `objdump` as suggested by @sharth).  Using `nm` is more 'portable' in that it is available on non-Linux Unix systems too; it is not much more portable because the output format is not completely standardized (though it is defined by POSIX, there are several common variations on the output format).